# '[[myView viewWithTag:tag] removeFromSuperview]' Removes all my UIButtons

Tags: ios, uiview

For some reason, I can't seem to remove a UIImageView without removing all of my UIButtons as well. All subviews were added to my main view _ourView and UIButtons were not given a tag (default 0) and my image was given a tag=5.

When I call

```
NSInteger o = [obj intValue]; //This is the letter "O" not 0, and o = 5 in this case (which is what my subview tag is)
UIView *hangmanView = [_ourView viewWithTag:o];
[hangmanView removeFromSuperview];
[_ourView setNeedsDisplay];
```

All of my buttons also disappear.

Any pointers?

EDIT: I have uploaded my project to github if you want to see more code. Here is the link to the file: https://github.com/elayman/Hangman/blob/master/Hangman/HangmanViewController.m#L172

Comment: Is the actual code an `o`, a `zero`, or a `five`?

Comment: what is the tag value for this view? It shouldn't be zero!

Comment: edits made - that is the letter o not 0. o=5 and I am NOT using IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 is the default for tag... so it takes the first view without a tag and that's probably not what you want.

Log what you remove so you can see what actually happens:

```
NSLog(@"removing %@", hangmanView)
```

Comment: My log shows the correct view being removed... very strange. It does not mention anything about my buttons.

Comment: I also checked my button superview and it is not equal to hangmanView being removed, nor do tho tags match.

Answer (score 1):

You've either added the buttons to your image view, or the view matching that tag is the superview of the buttons.

Check in the debugger what the tag value is (it may not be what you think it is) and what the view returned by viewWithTag is.

Tags are in most cases useless anyway. Why not use an outlet or outlet collection, it's far more explicit and readable.

Comment: maybe he is not using the interface builder ... I could understand that.

Comment: @Bastian, If not using IB, you can still store explicit references to subviews you need to access later. Tags are still rubbish.

Comment: they are less useful now when you use arc and can use weak references that auto nil ... but they still can be useful in some cases when you don't want to retain subviews of other views.

Comment: I am not using IB, I have 26 buttons and a dynamic number of imageviews on the screen - I do not want to store references to all of them if I don't have to

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I accidentally released my buttons after adding them to the superview so they were disappearing after the setNeedsDisplay. Thanks for your help. I'm just new to objective c and thought the addSubview message gave control of the subView to the superView.